# Silverlight client got NotFound error from WCF

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0

There are a lot of article on this subject, but neither helped me. I am trying to implement service which could be used without "Add Service Ref..." mostly with advice from hhttp://www.netfxharmonics.com/2008/11/Understanding-WCF-Services-in-Silverlight-2  .

I made small project to reproduce problem. 
http://hotfile.com/dl/96710945/9991ac3/SilverlightApplication8.zip.html

I tried solution like : 
- Handling Faults in Silverlight
- Cross domain policy
etc

All standard checks are done like, service is active and reachable, client succeed to create channel etc.

I am stack whole week with this problem and I can not figure it out.

Every help is appreciate.

Comment: You should set <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" /> and add service to the code-behind of the svc file without interfaces. That's how Silverlight works.

Comment: Using SvcTraceViewer.exe I found following error "Failed to lookup a channel to receive an incoming message. Either the endpoint or the SOAP action was not found."

Comment: vorrtex, I found implementation with interface http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2008/11/Understanding-WCF-Services-in-Silverlight-2 ,so it is possible. I will use your advice as last resort. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not go in deeper investigation, but I assume that service implementation class type was not good.

So my factory class looked like:

Public Class TimeServiceFactory
    Inherits System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactoryBase

```
Public Overrides Function CreateServiceHost(ByVal constructorString As String, ByVal baseAddresses() As System.Uri) As System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase
     Dim host As New ServiceHost(constructorString, baseAddresses)
```

It needs to be changed in:

Public Class TimeServiceFactory
    Inherits System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactoryBase

```
Public Overrides Function CreateServiceHost(ByVal constructorString As String, ByVal baseAddresses() As System.Uri) As System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase
    Dim host As New ServiceHost(GetType(TimeService), baseAddresses)
```

Difference is I did not pass constructorString (which has information of type of service implementation class) , I passed GetType(TimeService) instate, which provided correct type information.

Answer (score 0):

Denis,
try to create service in your web host project. Add service there and then you'll have a choice to add it as reference in your silverlight application. Just add a service in SilverlightApplication8.Web.  Right click on SilverlightApplication8.Web --> Add new Item --> On left choose Silverlight --> Silverlight-enabled WCF service. And then add reference to your SilverlightApplication8.

Comment: Damir, thanks for prompt response. Unfortunately, after following your instruction same error ocured.

Comment: You said add reference to you SilverlightApplication8. Did you meant Service reference. I implemented client manually so I can avoid "Add Service Ref..."